# Jquery .html, then .fadeout

Tags: jquery, fadein, innerhtml, fadeout

I am trying to update `.html('')`, then `delay(400)` and `fadeOut`, thereafter update `.html('')`,
and finally `fadeIn`again...

```
if(data==1) {
var html = "an other text" 
$('#nyhedsbrev').html('<br/><p style=\"width:100%; text-align:center;\">Tak for din tilmelding</p><br/>');
$('#nyhedsbrev').delay(2000).fadeOut().html(html).fadeIn();
 }
```

It works fine if I only use line two - or if I only try line one.
Together however, these won't work.

I have also tried to combine the two lines - deleting the second `$('#nyhedsbrev)`. 
Can you explain how I can first show the new text - then fade it out replace the innner html and then fade in?

- - - - clarify - - - 
        The problem is that the first part does not show - the fade out/in works...

Comment: `html(html)`???.. you havenot defined `html` anywhere.. or am i missing something

Comment: html is the inner html from before the if - that part works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jfiddle works..

http://jsfiddle.net/sN5e5/1/

```
$("#test").on('click', function(e) {
var oldhtml = "Tak for din tilmelding";
var newhtml = 'I m the new content of the div';
$('#nyhedsbrev').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#nyhedsbrev').html(newhtml).fadeIn();
    $('#nyhedsbrev').delay(2000);
    $('#nyhedsbrev').fadeIn(500, function() { $('#nyhedsbrev').html(oldhtml);  });
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut (and other animates methods) can take a callback as second argument.

```
if(data==1) { 
    var newhtml = html;
    $('#nyhedsbrev').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#nyhedsbrev').html(newhtml).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Working example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN5e5/)

Comment: +1 just one thing, by default fadeOut duration is 400 not 500

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this: 
- first store the original text - then show the temporary message - then fade out - then restore the original text - then fade in

Comment: Your solution only replaces the text - hence, it does not perform the actions I need...

Comment: delay works if there is an animation queue (http://api.jquery.com/delay/). If you need to "time" without / before animating item, you need to use setTimeout.